# How to call stored procedure if one of OUT variables data type is oracle.sql.array

Tags: database, stored-procedures, mule, dataweave

I am calling a stored procedure from my mule application with this code:

```
call StoredProcedureMine(:a,:b,:c)
```

'a' and 'b' are IN variables and 'C' variable is OUT variable, datatype of 'C' variable is array of objects (returned from fetch query).

Can you please help me syntax of 'C' while passing in OUT parameters, also what is datatype should I choose for 'C' in OUT parameters?

Answer (score 1):

This topic is explained in detail in the KB article: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Calling-Oracle-Stored-Procedure-with-User-Defined-Types-UDT-as-IN-OUT-or-IN-OUT-Parameters-in-Mule-4-x

Use the data type for arrays as in the following example:

```
<db:column-types>
    <db:column-type id="2003" typeName=<DB_ARRAY_TYPE_NAME> />
    ...
</db:column-types>
```